# How to ensure that it doesn't add zeroes before the numbers?

Tags: java, sorting, bigdecimal

```
import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;

class Solution
{
public static void main(String []args)
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int  cases  = in.nextInt();
    BigDecimal[] val = new BigDecimal[cases];
    for (int i = 0; i < cases; i++) {
        val[i] = in.nextBigDecimal();
    }

    List<BigDecimal> lnums = Arrays.asList(val);
    Collections.sort(lnums);

    for(int i = lnums.size()-1 ; i >=0 ; i--) {   
        System.out.println(lnums.get(i));
    }
}
}
```

my task here is to sort the big decimal array in a descending order but I can't understand where in my code am i going wrong and how can I achieve the expected output.

Your Output (stdout)

90

56.6

50

2.34

0.12

0.12

0.000

0

-100

Expected Output

90

56.6

50

02.34

0.12

.12

0

000.000

-100

Comment: where does it add any zeros ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you got BigDecimal you cannot distinguish was it entered as '0.12' or '.12'. So your only option is to perform your custom sorting before parsing BigDecimals.

Answer (score 0):

you read the the scanners input as BigDecimal (`in.nextBigDecimal()`)

thats the moment you "loose" the leading zeros. you must read them as String and compare them as BigDecimal. Doubt my solution is the best one but it should work.

```
String[] val = new String[cases];
for (int i = 0; i < cases; i++) {
    val[i] = in.nextLine();
}

List<string> lnums = Arrays.asList(val);

Collections.sort
  ( lnums
  , (String o1, String o2) 
    -> new BigDecimal(o2).compareTo(new BigDecimal(o1))
  )

for(int i = lnums.size()-1 ; i >=0 ; i--) {   
    System.out.println(lnums.get(i));
}
```